# Div overflow custom position

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to scroll to a desired position when the page loads. The scroll bar is inside a div. Here is the code:

```
function scroll()
{
    document.getElementById('content').scrollTo(500,500);
}
```

but its not working, any sugestions as my JavaScript is pretty bad???

Comment: `scrollTo` is a method of `window`, not an `Element` node. If you're trying to scroll an `Element`, set the `scrollTop` (and `scrollLeft`) properties

Comment: like this - document.getElementById('content').scrollTop(500)???

Comment: I said they are **properties**. You set properties with the assignment operator. So it would be like `someElement.scrollTop = 500;` as an example

Comment: What about if it's a <object>?????

Comment: What if **what** is an object?

Comment: var objDiv = document.getElementById("contents");
objDiv.scrollTop = 500;
objDiv.scrollLeft = 500; it doenst work...

Comment: instead of div, object as its a pdf.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's a PDF. Is it in an iframe? Is it embedded?

Comment: <object data="filename.pdf" type=\"application/pdf\"></object> it is embedded i guess.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot control the scroll of an embedded object from JavaScript. I don't know this feature is available, but you might look at the PDF.js library: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting Ian's comment to an answer:

`scrollTo` only applies to the window, not individual elements. These have `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` properties that you can change:

```
function scroll(elem,x,y) {
    elem.scrollLeft = x;
    elem.scrollTop = y;
}
// to call:
scroll(document.getElementById('content'),500,500);
```

Comment: I've done like you told me in the example... it still doesnt work.